# Why won't my AngularJS Spy function get called?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

My controller is:

```
webApp.controller 'AboutUsController', [
  '$scope'
  '$rootScope'
  ($scope, $rootScope) ->
    $scope.init = ->
      console.log 'About Us Page'

    $scope.init()
]
```

And in my Karma test, I have:

```
describe 'About Us Controller', ->
  $scope = null
  $rootScope = null
  controller = null

  beforeEach ->
    module 'webApp'

    inject ($injector) ->
      $rootScope = $injector.get '$rootScope'

      $scope = $rootScope.$new()
      $controller = $injector.get '$controller'

      controller = $controller 'AboutUsController',
        '$scope': $scope
        '$rootScope': $rootScope

      spyOn($scope, 'init').andCallThrough()

  it 'should should have an About Us Controller', ->
    expect(controller).not.toBe null
    expect(controller).not.toBe undefined

  it 'should call the init function', ->
    expect($scope.init).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Pretty simple, right? But I get `PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) About Us Controller should call the init function FAILED
    Expected spy init to have been called.`

Why would that be?

Comment: The problem is that your spy is created after `$scope.init()` has already been called (it fires upon instantiation of the controller)

Comment: So then how do I spy to see if `init` gets called?

Comment: Not as elegant, but instead of spying on `init()` write some tests to verify that the tasks that `init()` performs have occurred. Another idea is to move the work that `init()` performs into a service. This way you can instantiate the service and spy on it, before you create the controller.

Comment: Answer the question and I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of spying on init() write some tests to verify that the tasks that init() performs have occurred. Another idea is to move the work that init() performs into a service. This way you can instantiate the service and spy on it, before you create the controller.